# How to balance user-led vs. user-centered design when it comes to navigation labels?

Tags: navigation, user-expectation, user-research, labels, user-centered-design

We just completed some research with card sorting and tree testing. Two of the categories were consistently labeled the same by a large percentage of participants.

It seems to make sense to name the navigation item with the label most commonly found with our research, but at the same time that seems to clearly be "user-led" design.

For this particular facet of UX design is it ok for the approach to be more user-led vs. user-centered?

Comment: Isn't it in this case user-led and user-centered at the same time? It is not that you are following arbitrary user opinions, it is based on structured observations.

Comment: I guess that was my question. I need to "sell" this to my stakeholders and wanted to cover my bases on being prepared for any rebuttals. If someone were to say, "I thought we wanted to hear problems from customers, not solutions." Just curious how to frame this and how direct the results should be towards the implementation. Similar to what you said, maybe the response would be that this isn't just asking users for advice, it is gathering insight into how they think and process information?

Answer (score 0):

If your primary UX research found that the users had difficulty finding where to go to find certain content (e.g. navigation issues based on analytics and surveys), then the hypothesis of changing the labels to something more meaningful to the users to help improve the clarity can be tested by running your card sorting and tree-testing activities.

What this means is that you applied user-centric principles to come up with potential problems with the navigation or IA, came up with a user-centric hypothesis, and then chose a user-led research activity to come up with more user-centric labels to test the hypothesis in order to try and find a solution.

But I think it is clearer to simply say that you identified a potential problem that affects the user, and had input from them in order to test a solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> If someone were to say, "I thought we wanted to hear problems from customers, not solutions."

... then I would answer, "yes, that is partly true. In addition to problems, we also want to research what the users' model of the world is, to structure our solution so that it fits with their model of the world. And one aspect of their model is the categories they use. If a large majority of users does not make a distinction between two categories which we (= the development team) make, then we see a mismatch between our model and the users' model of the world."

And without more information about the categories, the users, and the use cases, I would say you should merge the two categories. Offering a choice where there is no choice in the users' head means they will make arbitrary choices, which might lead to them not reaching their goal, which will defeat the purpose of your design/application.